# propel-schema-reverse error : could not find driver

Tags: php, pdo, propel

Just started working with php and propel.

I am using Uniform Server (wamp server) and have db in mysql.

I am getting following error while running 'propel-gen test reverse'

```
propel > reverse:

[echo] +-----------------------------------------------+
[echo] | |
[echo] | Generating XML from PDO connection ! |
[echo] | |
[echo] +-----------------------------------------------+
[propel-schema-reverse] There was an error building XML from metadata: could not find driver
```

BUILD FINISHED

even error is not so much elaborated.

here is my build.properties

```
propel.home = .

propel.project = test

propel.targetPackage = lib.model

propel.packageObjectModel = true

propel.database = mysql

propel.database.driver = mysql

propel.database.url = mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_test

propel.database.user = myuser

propel.database.password = mypwd
```

please tell me how to resolve this problem and view description of the error.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable add line below to php-cli.ini to solve this problem

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Comment: this solved the problem for me, but in my case I had to edit the php.ini file (not php-cli.ini)

Answer (score 1):

You have to correct the url or dns.
For example, in my database.yml (I am using Propel under Symfony) you have to put someting like this:

```
all:
  propel:
    class: sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      classname: PropelPDO
      **dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sfjob'**
      username: root
      password: miyoko
      encoding: utf8
      persistent: true
      pooling: true
```

The important thing is the url: should be **mysql** and not **msql**

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try changing

```
propel.data.driver = mysql
```

To

```
propel.data.driver = mysqli
```

If it still does not work it may seem that WAMP does not ship with php PDO drivers.
Dunno i don't use WAMP but an alternative could be [XAMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Comment: tried but build failed. pdo_mysql module is not showing in php -m while it is enabled in php.ini. now going to try XAMP

Comment: Problem solved with XAMPP.
Unifrom server was not loading pdo_mysql module.
Propel is really a good ORM tool. 
Please suggest any framework zend /symfony/cakephp/codeigniter etc

Comment: I would suggest [Symfony](http://symfony.com) or [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com), the latter FuelPHP is easier to use and learn if used to codeigniter. But Symfony i find much more powerful and extensible, but with a higher learning curve especially when it comes to the user/security part it all depends on your php expertise. If you are a starter and want something easy to use i would suggest [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com) instead, also [Symfony](http://symfony.com) is more oriented towards [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org) these days